# Json Convert To and From Query String with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reflection

I have a string like `a=6&id=99` (i might store it in html as 'a=6&id=99' however thats not what js will see). I would like to convert that string into an object so i can do func(o.a); or o.id=44; How do i do that?

Part 2: How do i convert that object back to a query string? it would probably be trivial code that i can write.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Answer (score 11):

```
// convert string to object
str = 'a=6&id=99';
var arr = str.split('&');
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var bits = arr[i].split('=');
    obj[bits[0]] = bits[1];
}
//alert(obj.a);
//alert(obj.id);

// convert object back to string
str = '';
for(key in obj) {
    str += key + '=' + obj[key] + '&';
}
str = str.slice(0, str.length - 1); 
alert(str);
```

​    ​
Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/DUpQA/1/

Comment: You would need to make this function recursive to deal with all JSON objects?